# WebSocket: Multiple cryptos to display

Tags: javascript, binance

I understood how to display the course of a crypto for example `btc`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEJXh.png)

The problem is that I would like to display the price of BTC and the price of ETH at the same time.

But, I don't know how to do it? I am stuck when I should add several cyptos... :S

I have my code here below:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade');


let stockPriceElement = document.getElementById('btcStockPrice');
let lastPrice = null; 

ws.onmessage = (even) => {
  let stockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
  let price = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);

  stockPriceElement.innerText = price; 
  stockPriceElement.style.color = !lastPrice || lastPrice === price ? 'black' : price > lastPrice ? 'green' : 'red';
  lastPrice = price; 

}
```

I don't know how I should add `ethcusdt@trade` ?

Thank you for your help and your time.

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade');


let stockPriceElement = document.getElementById('btcStockPrice');
let lastPrice = null; 

ws.onmessage = (even) => {
  let stockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
  let price = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);

  stockPriceElement.innerText = price; 
  stockPriceElement.style.color = !lastPrice || lastPrice === price ? 'black' : price > lastPrice ? 'green' : 'red';
  lastPrice = price; 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container mt-3 pt-5">
    <hr>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead class="table-success">
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th>BTC</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <td><span id="btcStockPrice"></span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <thead class="table-success">
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th>ETH</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="text-center">
            <td><span id="ethStockPrice"></span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      
    </table>
    <hr>

  </div>


<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in different ways:

use the miniticker to get all info for all crypto and filter out to show only the ones you want :

> 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!miniTicker@arr'

or use a combined stream for the data you want:

> 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=btcusdt/ethusdt'